How to write audio data to a buffer from mediaDevices.getUserMedia when using react-native-webrtc
I am using react-native-webrtc for video calling. This part works fine. I need to intercept the audio stream and send it in chunks to the server.
I tried:
  this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(localStream);

  this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = async (event: any) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      const buffer = await event.data.arrayBuffer();
      ...
    }
  };

But MediaRecorder is not in react-native.
How can this be done? Well, the microphone is available, the audio stream is going. I just need to capture and record it.
